# Adding subtitles to products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta-boxes

I'd like to be able to add a subtitle to my products in Woocommerce only on the shop page. I have it set up as a catalog right now, since I'm not actively selling my products yet, so I have disabled the add to cart button and the prices. I would like to be able to say how many colors the product comes in as a subtitle. I have read up on adding meta boxes with Woocommerce, and found this solution and added it to my functions.php, but it doesn't appear to be working on my site (I can't find where to enter the information for the product!)

```
add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'bhww_core_cpt_metaboxes' );

function bhww_core_cpt_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {

    //global $prefix;
    $prefix = '_bhww_'; // Prefix for all fields

    // Add metaboxes to the 'Product' CPT
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id'         => 'bhww_woo_tabs_metabox',
        'title'      => 'Additional Product Information - <strong>Optional</strong>',
        'pages'      => array( 'product' ), // Which post type to associate with?
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'default',
        'show_names' => true,                   
        'fields'     => array(
            array(
                'name'    => __( 'Colors', 'cmb' ),
                'desc'    => __( 'Anything you enter here will be displayed on the Colors tab.', 'cmb' ),
                'id'      => $prefix . 'ingredients_wysiwyg',
                'type'    => 'wysiwyg',
                'options' => array( 'textarea_rows' => 5, ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $meta_boxes;

}
```

Comment: Are you using the CMB metaboxes plugin? If you only need a subtitle then yours truly wrote a subtitle plugin. See [KIA Subtitle](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kia-subtitle/) And here's my [bridge plugin](https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/ffbf9d1c82351fb9220ff91ce61f7518) that adds the subtitles to WooCommerce products.

Comment: Thanks - where do I put the code for the bridge plugin, in the functions.php or somewhere else?

Comment: No, it's a plugin. Upload it to the wp-content/plugins folder and activate it.